# Using Apex class in salesforce community site

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, database

I'm working on a very simple project that uses google books API and I have a problem. I want to save all search history in an object in database and all works fine when I'm logged in my account and all history records to a base, but when random user want to find some books I have this error:

[image]

How I can fix this?

My code:

searchList.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <article class="slds-card">
            <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                    <div class="slds-media__body">
                      <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
                          <span class="slds-text-heading_small slds-truncate slds-align_absolute-center">Books</span>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                <div class="slds-m-bottom_x-small slds-wrap slds-grid slds-gutters">
                    <lightning-input type="text"
                        value={searchTitleValue}
                        label="Book title"
                        onchange={updateSearchTitleValue}
                        class="slds-col"
                    ></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text"
                        value={searchAuthorValue}
                        label="Author"
                        onchange={updateSearchAuthorValue}
                        class="slds-col"
                    ></lightning-input>
                </div>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand slds-button_stretch" onclick={findBooks}>Find Book(s)</button>
                <lightning-layout class="slds-p-around_xx-small slds-grid slds-grid_pull-padded slds-wrap slds-grid_align-center">
                    <template for:each={Books} for:item='Book'>
                            <lightning-layout-item class="slds-m-around_xx-small slds-size_3-of-12 slds-box" key={Book.id} data-id={Book.id}>
                                <h2 class="slds-text-align_center"><b>{Book.volumeInfo.title}</b></h2>
                                <p class="slds-text-align_center">{Book.volumeInfo.authors}</p>
                                <img class="slds-align_absolute-center" src="">
                                <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="" class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-around_x-small">
                                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_success">Go to shop</button> 
                                </a>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                    </template>
                </lightning-layout> 
            </div>
        </article>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

searchList.js

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import addBookRecord from '@salesforce/apex/searchListController.addBookRecord';
export default class BooksSearch extends LightningElement {
    
    @track Books;
    searchTitleValue = '';
    searchAuthorValue = '';

    async findBooks()
    {
        if(this.searchTitleValue !== '')
        {   
            addBookRecord({title: this.searchTitleValue, author: this.searchAuthorValue});
            let tempTitle = this.searchTitleValue.replace(/ /g, '_');
            let tempAuthor = '';
            if(this.searchAuthorValue !== '')
            {
                let tempList = this.searchAuthorValue.split(' ');
                tempAuthor = '+inauthor:' + tempList[tempList.length - 1];
            }
            let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + tempTitle + tempAuthor +'&maxResults=40&key=[myKey]'
            let fetchResult = await fetch(url);
            let jsonString = await fetchResult.json();
            this.Books = jsonString.items;
            console.log(jsonString);
        }
        setTimeout(() => { 
            let size = this.Books.length;
            for(let i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                let bookImage;
                let shopLink;
                
                if(this.Books[i].saleInfo.saleability == "FOR_SALE"){
                    shopLink = this.Books[i].saleInfo.buyLink;
                } else {
                    shopLink = this.Books[i].volumeInfo.canonicalVolumeLink;
                }
                if(this.Books[i].volumeInfo.hasOwnProperty('imageLinks')) {
                    bookImage = this.Books[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
                } else {
                    bookImage = 'https://i.postimg.cc/RZ3rrN0Y/noBook.png'
                }                
                //let bookId = this.Books[i].id;
                this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' + this.Books[i].id + '"]').querySelector("a").setAttribute("href", shopLink);
                this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' + this.Books[i].id + '"]').querySelector("img").setAttribute("src", bookImage);
                //element.setAttribute("src", bookImage);
            }
        } , 500);
    }

    updateSearchTitleValue(event)
    {
        this.searchTitleValue = event.target.value;
    }

    updateSearchAuthorValue(event)
    {
        this.searchAuthorValue = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

meta file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

And my Apex class

```
public without sharing class searchListController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void addBookRecord(String title, String author){
        if(String.isNotBlank(title) && author != null)
        {
            book_query__c newQuery = new book_query__c();
            newQuery.title_query__c = title;
            newQuery.author_query__c = author;
            newQuery.title_and_author__c = title + author;
            upsert newQuery title_and_author__c;
        }
    }
}
```

meta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant Profile access to the Apex class `searchListController`. If, as sounds to be the case, you're intending to expose this functionality to unauthenticated users through a public Community, you'd need to add it to the Site Guest User profile for that Community.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your random user's community profile needs to have access to your apex class, `searchListController`. Do the same for your guest user's community profile as well if unauthenticated users need to run this component as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!